# WSP package stuck in retracting state

Tags: wss-3.0, installation, solution-package

We are tring to run an update script. As part of this script we use stsadm command retractsolution and then deletesolution to remove the wsp packages.

Our problem is that on the last run several of our packages are stuck in the retracting state.

Anyone know what causes this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you always deploying solutions from the same WFE always? You should!

execadmsvcjobs *only* flushes the jobs running on current WFE. 
Hence if you have stalled jobs on other WFE you can get inconsistent behaviour and jobs tend to get stuck.

Gary Lapointes gl-execadmsvcjobs have helped me out before in situations like that before, since it executes across WFE.
http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2008/10/better-execadmsvcjobs-stsadm-command.html

Answer (score 2):

It will may help to restart the Timer Service.

Answer (score 1):

Does your script run stsadm with -o execadmsvcjobs after the retract command?

Comment: Yes, we run it after each retract sloution and delete solution

Comment: You could try manually executing the retract step, going into Central Admin to manually execute the timer job and seeing the results.
Also, are there any clues in the ULS or Event Logs?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd check is make sure the Timer Service is actually running on all front-end servers :-)

Comment: @Paul, yes we checked, it is running on all servers

Answer (score 1):

do a restart.. it worked for us